# how to Bind dynamic views using butterknife

Tags: android, fragment, butterknife

i am creating the multiple dynamic views in android and my fragment using the layout of parent fragment and in child fragment i am creating the dynamic views but i am not able to bind those dynamic views using Butterknife.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
this is the on create 
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); this.container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.overall_sport_performance_row, null), 5);
```

**i have one textview in the overall_sport_performance layout and i want to use that using butterknife**

Comment: What have you tried till now? Try overriding onViewCreated and add this "ButterKnife.bind(this, view);" in that method

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your solution, if your Fragment's view is `overall_spot_performance.xml`, do like this:

```
@BindView(R.id.your_text_view_id)
protected TextView textView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.overall_sport_performance_row, null);
    Butterknife.bind(this, view);

    return view;
}
```

No need to bind the TextView dynamically. However if you still need to bind it dynamically, you can use `findById` method. I did not test it but should work like this:

```
View dynamicView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overall_sport_performance_row, null);
this.container.addView(dynamicView, 5);

TextView textView = ButterKnife.findById(dynamicView, R.id.your_text_view_id);
```